# Speaker creates distorted sound on certain battry level acer

Tags: audio, hardware-failure, battery, speakers, acer-aspire

The problem started with my speakers sound being distorted when connected to the charger for a few seconds. If I disconnect it from the charges, the sound would get back to normal.
After a while, I disconnected my battery and the problem was gone. The sound worked fine with the charger being connected when there was not a battery connected to my Acer laptop.

Then I bought a new battery and connected it and the problem was back. The sound would go interrupted and after some minutes totally gone when I connect the charger.

Recently, the problem expanded to even when the charger is not connected and it will be gone some minutes after the battery level reaches 100%(still connecting to charger).

It now became unpredictable when it will disrupt!

And also the problem exists on both Windows10 and ubuntu.

Can you please share your thought?